# Conflicting assets with the same target path

Tags: c#, razor

I published my code out of Visual Studio 2022.
I accidently pasted my Published code in the same directory as my "source code".

Now I'm getting " ERROR Conflicting assets with the same target path...."

I deleted the bin and obj directories. And removed all other files.

Any suggestions?

TIA.

Comment: Close VS, delete all the code you accidentally pasted, then delete the .vs, bin, and obj files before opening visual studio. If that doesn't seem to work, try deleting all your working files and restore from source control directly.

Comment: That did not work. It was error on same path of <b>Identity\css\site.css</b> I have been using this same code for several months. SOLUTIION ( I will see what else breaks in the future) I renamed folder to <b>"Identity_2"</b>